# Blender material missing undefined socket

Tags: blenderkit

[image]I downloaded a sample start blender file for swimming pool model and found the material in the node model are all "undefined sockets". Do I miss any add ons and how do I know what add ons the authors used?

See the pictures.
Thanks

Comment: Compare the blender version from the blend file with your blender version --> console: head -c 12 yourfile.blend

Comment: Thanks! IThe file  version -v291 and I am using v302. I tried V291 and still have the same problem. My file is downloaded from youtube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9HerjxC5bs&t=7s and I believe it either used some addon or did not include the material file.

Comment: The address of the file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjudzv4aj5lg1z2/pool-starter-file.blend?dl=0

Comment: this is not a material, but Geometry nodes. Since you are using a pretty old blender version, i would recommend downloading Blender version > 3.1, then it should work

Comment: I was using MAC 3.2.2 version when I encountered the problem. I then downgraded it to 2.91 and still have the problem. (interestingly, when I save the file and using Secrop's suggestion, the file version is V302.

Comment: I also do not find edit preference -experimental missing in 3.2.3 version so I can not turn on Preferences > Experimental and turn on "Geometry Nodes Legacy"

Comment: @testComments, The problem is not related to GeometryNodes... All those nodes are not builtin Blender nodes.. they are Material Nodes from LuxCore Render. That means you need to install LuxCore and the respective Addon for Blender in order for them to work! (check the first link in the youtube)